# Sorting in Apache Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark and I am reading files from HDFS directory and then filtering and ordering based on condition.

I have two files in a hdfs directory 
First file containing data like below

```
Name:xxxx,currenttime:[timestamp],urlvisited:[url]
```

Second file containing following information

```
Name:xxxx,currenttime :[timestamp],downloadfilename:[filename]
```

First I am filtering the data based on Name and then I am splitting the data using comma and then I am ordering the data using the fields currenttime

So far I have tried

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class SampleVisit {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String name = args[0];

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sample");
        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/sample/*/",1);

        JavaRDD<String> filterdata = lines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(String s) {
                return s.contains("Name:" + name);
            }
        });

    //Returning all other values as one fields and currenttime as another field
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,String>> stage2 = filterdata.map(new Function<String, Tuple2<String,String>>() {

            public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws ParseException {

               String [] entries = s.split(",");



                return new Tuple2(s[0]+","+s[2], s[1]);
            }
        });



        List<Tuple2<String,String>> sorted = stage2.takeOrdered(100, new CompareValues()) ;

       JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,String>> finale = ctx.parallelize(sorted);
       finale.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/sampleout");

    }
}
```

And my CompareValues.java is shown below

```
public class CompareValues implements Comparator<Tuple2<String,String>>, Serializable {

        @Override

        public int compare(Tuple2<String, String> o1, Tuple2<String, String> o2) {
            long first = Long.valueOf(o1._2);
            long second = Long.valueOf(o2._2);
             Date firstDate = new Date(first);
             Date secondDate = new Date(second);

             return secondDate.compareTo(firstDate);

}
}
```

when I run this with Name value as argument all are running as expected but the result returns the data in which the first file values  are in an ordered manner and then second file values are ordered but I wantthe result in which both file values in an ordered manner
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from coalescing your RDD with `shuffle=true`. This means that the RDD is shuffled using an hash partitioner and each item is sent to the proper partition. Thus, the items are ordered within the partition, but they are not in general. When you save it to a file, each partition is written to a separate file, to allow concurrent writes.

If you want the result to be ordered across all the partitions, you need to set a partitioner which guarantees that all the "close" items are in the same partition.

Look at the **Data Partitioning** chapter [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html) for further explanations.